# Head First Design Patterns - Decorator Pattern using Starbuzz

Tags: oop, design-patterns, decorator

I am going through the book Head First Design Patterns and am specifically looking at the Starbuzz example for the `Decorator` pattern.

I am having trouble understanding that what exactly is the need for `CondimentDecorator` in the example provided. Why can't `Mocha` simply extend `Beverage`? What's the need for another layer of abstraction?`

```
public abstract class Beverage  
{  
   String description = "Unknown beverage";

    public String getDescription()
   {
     return description; 
   }

   public abstract double cost();  
}  

public abstract class CondimentDecorator extends Beverage  
{  
    public abstract String getDescription();
}  

public class Mocha extends CondimentDecorator
{  
   Beverage b;

   public Mocha(Beverage b)
   {
     this.b=b;
   }

   public String getDescription()
   {
      return b.getDescription() + ", Mocha";
   }

   public double cost()
   {
     return .20 + b.cost();
   }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at CompressionStream and Encryption stream in .Net

Comment: Also its better suited here.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ also

Comment: @samyismyhero Code Revieww is not about explaining code. This is off-topic for Code Review. (And I don't think it's on-topic on Programmers either).

Comment: @samyismyhero well... it's textbook example code, Code Review is for posting *your own* working code. If OP implements their own decorator in an actual application, then yes, it would be on-topic to ask whether the decorator pattern is overkill on CR.

Comment: The answer to your question is in the chapter (Head First is an extremely well written book). The [topics](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for programmers.stackexchange.com seem to allow for this kind of question; it's clearly a question about `software architecture and design`.

Comment: Oh, and this sounds a lot like a homework question I might give. Is it one?

Comment: No, it's not a homework question. Can't someone try to learn something without it being homework? FWIW, I am not in school/college.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in the sample you posted it isin't that clear, but the abstract class usually takes care of the component encapsulation and the default method implementations are to delegate method calls to that component.

Therefore, when implementing concrete decorators, you would't have to override all methods if you don't need to.

e.g.

```
public abstract class CondimentDecorator extends Beverage {  
    Beverage beverageToDecorate;

    public CondimentDecorator(Beverage beverageToDecorate) {
        this.beverageToDecorate = beverageToDecorate;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return beverageToDecorate.getDescription();
    }

    public double cost() {
        return beverageToDecorate.cost();
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I have the Beverage instance in the concrete decorator what's the advantage of using an abstract decorator on top of it? The example you showed is only returning the field values on the Beverage instance, something I can do in the concrete decorator too.

Comment: @collegian Yes, but now you do not have to duplicate that code in all concrete decorators plus you get to override only the methods you need in concrete decorators, not all of them. In this specific case, you would probably always override both methods, but that's not true with every decorators.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I guess, I will try and look at some better examples.

Comment: @collegian Have a look at the ones on Wikipedia. You will see that they make use of the abstract class for the purpose I described.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't Mocha simply extend Beverage? What's the need for another layer of abstraction?

The problem is how to deal with the combinations. `Mocha` is only one variant, but what about Mocha + House Blend + Steam Milk, etc. There's a lovely image on p.81 of the design solution using only this "layer" which has so many classes inheriting from `Beverage` that it's a "maintenance nightmare."

The `CondimentDecorator` allows adding any number of combinations to your `Beverage` through *composition* rather than *inheritance*.

Comment: I guess, I can see the duplication happening if new methods are introduced in Beverage and some of them are common across all condiments. Can you give some more examples of maintenance nightmare? I thought the image on Page 81 showed every possible scenario in it's own class and hence was different from the above scenario where each Condiment and each concrete beverage is it's own class. Also, the current scenario uses Beverage instance in each of the concrete condiments. If Mocha+ House Blend+ Milk comes in then mocha and milk will calculate their own cost and add to the House Blend's cost.

Comment: No, it's not about new methods. It's about combining variants of condiments and beverages. p.81 also has condiments. All the examples you need are there. It doesn't get any worse than a class called `HouseBlendWithWhipandSoy`! As for calculating costs, see pp.89-90. Decorators wrap other Beverages.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. The image on page 81 is different from the question I am asking. In page 81 every possible variant is combined into a single class and I do see class explosion. In the above scenario every Condiment and Beverage is it's own class and there is no combination taking place.

Comment: My book's p81 has a diagram of 20+ subclasses of Beverage and an image following it of a guy saying "talk about class explosion"

Comment: Combination takes place by wrapping (composition). Mocha wraps Soya that wraps HouseBlend.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I think you are missing OP's point. Wheter you have the abstract `CondimentDecorator` class or not you can still apply the decorator pattern. For each decorators you would have to inherit `Beverage` and encapsulate another `Beverage` instance. `CondimentDecorator` is not necessary, but it does reduce code duplication. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @plalx ok, so I understand your answer to a question about creating a bunch of concrete decorators without the abstraction. But OP doesn't clearly say Mocha "is a" decorator (you infer it and you might be right). If Mocha extends beverage, that implies Mocha "is-a" Beverage. If it extends Decorator, Mocha "is-a" Decorator. OP should clarify if this is the case.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Well in the OP's code you can read `public class Mocha extends CondimentDecorator` so that's pretty clear to me.