# Decorator Design Pattern Ambigous

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

Let take simple class diagram as an example

[image]

My Question is **why** do we need `OptionalWrapper` ? Isn't it enough that `OptionalOne`, `OptionalTwo` and `OptionalThree` implements `Interface` because all we need is the `Interface` type of object in the decorator classes.

Comment: Using `OptionalWrapper` allows for dependency injection in the class. That way, you can change the implementation details in `OptionalWrapper` and never need to change anything in `OptionalOne`, `OptionalTwo`, `OptionalThree`.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/28269262/1168342

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OptionalWrapper` is where you add a reference to the class you're decorating, and redirect all of its methods to that instance. If you don't have `OptionalWrapper`, then you'd need to repeat this code in each of its subclasses. In the given diagram, each one of the subclasses only needs to override the behavior they're supposed to modify.

Comment: `doThis()` will be implemented by all of the optionalOne/Two/Three classes ... `OptionalWrapper` will not gonna implement `doThis()`. And in OptionalWrapper we donot add the reference to the class you'are decorating, we add the reference in the OptionalOne/Two/Three classes ...

Comment: @Junaid What if the interface has other methods than `doThis()`? Do you want to repeat the code in all of the subclasses?

Comment: So **1)** `OptionalWrapper` is just for resuibility, right? And **2)** it doesn't play any good role in Decorating the objects, right?

Comment: @Junaid Yes, both of those are correct. `OptionalWrapper` just exposes a bunch of methods that call the corresponding methods on the `wrapee` instance. You do the decorating in its subclasses by overriding some of those methods.

Answer (score 2):

A more concrete example: you want to add exception handling. You can do this once in the OptionalWrapper and be finished, or you can implement it in each of the three subclasses (and every new class you have that implements the interface).

Answer (score 0):

1) In your example if you decide to add new behaviors in all of the decorators `OptionalOne`, `OptionalTwo` and `OptionalThree` then you will add a new method in `Interface` but that impacts `CoreFunactionality`. So to separate this you need one more interface/abstract class `OptionalWrapper`.

2) All decorators just need to deal with `OptionalWrapper` and do not worry about what instance it is decorating.

Answer (score 0):

Here optional wrapper is your Decorator class which will be abstract in most cases. It enhances an object's responsibilities. If you add some more functionalities in your interface which need not to be implemented in your optional classes(optional1, optiona2 and etc), you'll need an abstract optional wrapper.